# AWK over few columns

Tags: awk

I have file like this:

```
52.17.30.11 10.1.1.2 76 ACCEPT
54.19.18.100 10.25.13.18 1140 ACCEPT
10.25.13.136 10.24.13.166 275074 ACCEPT
54.72.7.17 10.24.13.166 152 ACCEPT
```

I'd like to do AWK over first two IPs to recognize whether they are internet, internal1 or the rest.  In this case, I'd like to get this result:

```
Internet 10.1.1.2 76 ACCEPT
Internet internal1 1140 ACCEPT
internal1 10.24.13.166 275074 ACCEPT
Internet 10.24.13.166 152 ACCEPT
```

So if this is `10.25`, this is internal1. Else if this is `10.`, this is "the rest" and if this is something else - this is Internet

No issues doing that over the first IP:

```
cat x | awk -F. '{if($1 == 10 && $2 == 25) { print "internal1 " } else if($1 == 10) { print $0 } else {print "Internet "}
```

However, the result would be:

```
Internet
Internet
internal1
Internet
```

SO what is missing is 1st) the rest of each line and 2nd) check of 2nd IP

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=2;i++) { 
    if ($i ~ /^10\.25\./) $i="internal1"; 
    else if ($i !~ /^10\./) $i="Internal"} }1' x
```

Comment: typo, should be `$i="Internet"` on 3rd line